# Getting class simple name (including wrapping class!)

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class and want to get it's name for display.

```
Class<?> cls = obj.getClass();
```

Let's say the `obj` is an instance of `KeyDownEvent.Listener` (nested interface within `KeyEvent`).

- If I use `cls.getSimpleName()`, I get `Listener` - there can be more with that name easily.
- If I use `cls.getName()`, I get the full name with packages - exact, but not very easy for reading in a log.

Any idea how to get `"KeyDownEvent.Listener"` from the `cls`?

---

Note that I want to use the result in a log.

While `KeyDownEvent.Listener` is not exact as there can be multiple classes with such name in different packages, I am going to take the risk. It's nicer than the whole name with packages.

Comment: Just get a substring.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a magical method for parsing a string exactly how you want it to be parsed, or are you asking us to write one for you?

Comment: Yes, actually I was looking for `cls.getEnclosingClass().

Comment: I have found that including the package name of the class helps more that not having it, specially when there are more than one class with that name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've found a solution, could help someone else.

The trick is `class.getEnclosingClass()`:

```
Class<?> cls = obj.getClass();
Class<?> enclosing = cls.getEnclosingClass();
return 
    (enclosing == null ? "" : enclosing.getSimpleName() + ".")
    + cls.getSimpleName();
```